# How to enable HTML5 Canvas Pan effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, zooming, pan

I'm following a code on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-zoom-in-on-a-point-using-scale-and-translate/ where a user can Zoom in and out from an HTML 5 Canvas.

I want to add the functionality of Canvas Pan (so that I can move a number of objects easily).

The code below

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    </center>
    <script>
        var zoomIntensity = 0.1;
  
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = canvas.clientWidth;
        var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  
        var scale = 1;
        var orgnx = 0;
        var orgny = 0;
        var visibleWidth = width;
        var visibleHeight = height;

    draw();
  
        function draw() {
            context.fillStyle = "white";
            context.fillRect(orgnx, orgny, width / scale, height / scale);
            context.fillStyle = "green";
            context.fillRect(250,50,100,100); 
        }
          
        canvas.onwheel = function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var x = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            var y = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            var scroll = event.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -2;
  
            var zoom = Math.exp(scroll * zoomIntensity);
  
            context.translate(orgnx, orgny);
  
            orgnx -= x / (scale * zoom) - x / scale;
            orgny -= y / (scale * zoom) - y / scale;
  
            context.scale(zoom, zoom);
            context.translate(-orgnx, -orgny);
  
            // Updating scale and visisble width and height
            scale *= zoom;
            visibleWidth = width / scale;
            visibleHeight = height / scale;
        draw();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to change the **orgnx** and **orgny** to create pan effect, but its not working. Even when I call `context.translate(orgnx, orgny);` to create Pan effect, it doesn't work well. How I can enable Canvas Pan effect without compromising the Zoom. I know I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. In order to pan the canvas in the above code

```
context.translate(orgnx, orgny);
orgnx += distX * (1/scale);
orgny += distY * (1/scale);
context.translate(-orgnx, -orgny);
draw();
```

**distX** and **distY** are respective distances to pan the canvas